# Woocommerce product page not showing price for update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[There is no option for updating product price and product variation and other tabs are not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPegV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably selected `External Product`. Switch it back to `Simple Product`.

[image]